# Checking if the wiki page content already exists before saving or editing an enterprise wiki page

Tags: 2013, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

We are working on an enterprise wiki site collection inside SP 2013; currently we have been running the site collection for more than a year. But we start realizing that some users are adding almost the same content inside two different wiki pages.

So my question is if SharePoint provides any mean by which I can check if the wiki page content already exists or similar content already exists prior to adding or editing the wiki page?

Comment: Real time capturing something like this will be a tedious process. I would suggest you can create a Complex Job which runs every day and look for duplicate content. (Since its WIKI and uses HTML enabled content it will be a real challenge to find matches)

Comment: but i do not want to search for exactly the same content !!

Answer (score 1):

No there is nothing like this ootb. You might be able to rig up something that takes input from when they create the page title and leverage search to pull back a list of possible matches, just like how the stack exchange sites work.

Comment: sound a valid approach but how does SP support this ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have an OOTB solution for this however there are various features that might make this process easier and more reliable:

- Establish good naming conventions ("the horse" is not a well-accepted
  name, one would naturally choose "horse") so that editors will
  naturally give the same name to the same subject.
- Make it easy for editors to find similar articles.
- Make it easy to flag articles as duplicates or delete them.
- Make sensible restrictions so that vandals can't mis-use these
  features to remove genuine content from your site.

Comment: all these points are valid ,, but how does SP supports this ? your reply can be a good question,, so how i can flag articles as duplicate ,, is there any support from SP regarding these points?

Comment: you can create termsets and tag the articles in the respective categories. this makes things easy in finding the articles as well you can find the duplicate entries by searching in the respective categores and redirecting it to the original article post.

Comment: i already use meta data and tags,, but this will not help in finding duplicate content.